# LambdaExpression Variable Referenced From Scope But Not Defined

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I have a simple lambda expression that I would like to compile and invoke

```
Expression< Func< Commands, bool>> expression = c => c.IsValid("test");
```

but when I do the following:

```
LambdaExpression le = Expression.Lambda(expression.Body);

object result = le.Compile().DynamicInvoke();
```

the compile throws the error:

> variable 'c' of type 'ConsoleApplication1.Commands' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

How do you set the instance variable for this expression?

Answer (score 4):

Why not just compile the expression itself? If you'd like to invoke it with some specific 'ConsoleApplication1.Commands' instance multiple times you could then just close over that instance:

```
var validator = expression.Compile();

var c = new Commands();
var validatorForC = () => validator(c);
```

Otherwise you'll need to build call expression, like this:

```
var c = new Commands();
var le = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Invoke(expression, Expression.Constant(c)));
object result = le.Compile().DynamicInvoke();
```

or you can make ExpressionVisitor which will replace all occurences of the 'c' parameter in 'expression.Body' with Expression.Constant.

Comment: I did not want compile the expression directly because i am parsing it to convert it into another language/syntax.  the solution for me is to create an BlockExpression and within that expression assign the argument to a instance of the object i want. (only took me a day to figure this out...)